# why is excel automaticaly changin my value from mm:ss,000 to hh:mm:ss?

Tags: excel, office365

when I insert in the cell the value "02:20,365" it should stay like that but when I check what's inside the cell it changes in "00:02:20".

I don't know what is causing the problem or what could be the cause, I'm using that values inside a table but the column is set to have the custom format (mm:ss,000)

The table is also used in a pivot table and also there the column storing this value is set to "mm:ss,000" and there is the same problem.

what could be the cause, I should also mention that I have little to none experience with pivot table so it could be there the error but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula bar cannot be formatted to show milliseconds.

To get the milliseconds to show up in the pivot table, format your source data as general, and format the pivot table as "mm:ss,000"

If you need to see the milliseconds in the source data and the pivot table, consider adding a duplicate column in the source data, so you have 1 column formatted with milliseconds, and a duplicate column formatted as general.